# Unable to get properties binding in Spring Boot Autoconfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've got a very simple use case in Spring Boot to override the management port of Spring Actuator however the properties from `application.yml` do not seem to bind.

This is the properties class,

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test.metrics", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class MetricsProperties {
    private boolean enabled = true;
    private final Management management = new Management();

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public static class Management {
        private String contextPath = "/management";
        private int port = 9079;

        public String getContextPath() {
            return this.contextPath;
        }

        public void setContextPath(String contextPath) {
            this.contextPath = contextPath;
        }

        public int getPort() {
            return this.port;
        }

        public void setPort(int port) {
            this.port = port;
        }
    }
}
```

My autoconfiguration class,

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MetricsProperties.class)
@AutoConfigureBefore({ ManagementServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class })
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "test.metrics", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class MetricsAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ManagementServerProperties managementServerProperties(MetricsProperties metricsProperties) {
        log.debug("Initializing management context");
        log.debug("{}", metricsProperties); // Always shows 9079
        ManagementServerProperties managementServerProperties = new ManagementServerProperties();
        managementServerProperties.setContextPath(metricsProperties.getManagement().getContextPath());
        managementServerProperties.setPort(metricsProperties.getManagement().getPort());
        managementServerProperties.getSecurity().setEnabled(false);
        return managementServerProperties;
    }
}
```

I do load this autoconfiguration class via `spring.factories`,

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
co.test.metrics.metricscollector.MetricsAutoConfiguration
```

However, having `application.yml` the following property does not work.

```
test:
  metrics:
    management:
      port: 9999
```

It always defaults to `9079` port.

Can someone please point at what Im doing wrong here ? I can see that `MetricsProperties` getting injected as it doesnt throw a NPE.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have final fields in `@ConfigurationProperties` classes and these classes also should adhere to the bean spec (have getters and setters). Make your class look like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test.metrics", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class MetricsProperties {
    private boolean enabled = true;
    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Management management;

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public void setManagement(Management management) {
        this.management = management;
    }

    public Management getManagement() {
        return this.management;
    }

    public static class Management {
        private String contextPath = "/management";
        private int port = 9079;

        public String getContextPath() {
            return this.contextPath;
        }

        public void setContextPath(String contextPath) {
            this.contextPath = contextPath;
        }

        public int getPort() {
            return this.port;
        }

        public void setPort(int port) {
            this.port = port;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately now it throws a NPE at `managementServerProperties.setContextPath(metricsProperties.getManagement().getContextPath());` where `getManagement` returns null